# I want to insert this stripe checkout form into my HTML, but since it's been inserted after the DOM, it won't work. Can you get me on the right path?

Tags: javascript, dom, stripe-payments

I am building a donation page where someone can enter in multiple amounts. So far, the Stripe Checkout button works, but only for one value at a time.

So this works, but I need a way to change the value of Amount in that script.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="[MY TEST KEY"
    data-amount="2000" // <-- this is what I need to change.
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
    data-image="/128x128.png">
  </script>
</form>
```

I thought perhaps one way to do that would be to generate the entire form *after* the user selects an amount.  (which also makes sense for UX reasons.)

So, I wrote this function, which replaces (in my sandbox) a div with the id of "checkout button":

```
   var processCustomAmount = function(value){
      amountCents = Math.floor(value * 100);
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = amountCents;

        var formPart1 = '<form action="';
        var formPart2 = '" method="POST"><script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button" data-key="[MY TEST KEY]" data-amount="';
        var formPart3 = '"data-name="SendThisGuy" data-description="Donation to Send This Guy To Code Camp" data-image="/images/stripe-thisguy.png"></script></form>';

      document.getElementById("checkoutButton").outerHTML = formPart1 + formAction + formPart2 + amountCents + formPart3;
    };
```

The idea was that I could use basic Javascript to get the correct amount that people want to donate, then insert those as variables into a large string which contains the form needed.

When I look in the console/sources, it does put the code in the source, but the problem is that that HTML has come in AFTER the page has loaded.  So I don't think the page will actually execute the script in the page and generate the button.

Keep in mind, I'm a beginner, so I only know some basic javascript. I don't know jQuery, meaning that if you give me some regular javascript code to use, I can probably figure out how it works and how to impliment it, but if you just paste jQuery code, I'm going to have no idea what it does or how to use it.